# docker command not found - bash script

Tags: bash, docker, macos

I've bash script to load docker images once the application is installed (postinstall script).

Using command manually on the terminal is working, but from postinstall script getting:

```
docker: command not found
```

Tried, executing docker with absolute path (which docker) adding the path variable of docker  (execute PATH=\usr\bin\docker:$PATH)

Is there something wrong with my macOS or script is wrong.

Original script:
I m checking the macOS chip and then using command docker info trying if docker is installed  if its installed loading the images from the working directory otherwise installing docker first and then loading images.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
#

CheckVar=`which docker`
echo "$CheckVar"

if [[ `sysctl machdep.cpu.brand_string` == *"Intel"* ]]
then
    if [[ `$CheckVar info` == *"Client"* ]];
    then
        echo "Mac Chip is Intel"
        echo "Docker found!"
        cd $Home/$DSTROOT/App
        echo "Redirected to working dir.."
        sudo `$CheckVar load -i app.tar`
        echo "Success"
    else
        echo "Mac Chip is Intel"
        echo "Docker not found installing"
        cd $Home/$DSTROOT/App
        echo "Redirected to working dir.."
        sudo hdiutil attach IntelDocker.dmg
        sudo /Volumes/Docker/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/install
        sudo hdiutil detach /Volumes/Docker
        sudo `$CheckVar load -i app.tar`
        echo "Success"
    fi
else
    if [[ `$CheckVar info` == *"Client"*  ]];
    then
        echo "Mac Chip is AppleSilicon"
    echo "Docker found!"
        cd $Home/$DSTROOT/App
        echo "Redirected to working dir.."
    sudo `$CheckVar load -i app.tar`
    echo "Success"
    else
        echo "Mac Chip is AppleSilicon"
        echo "Docker not found installing"
        cd $Home/$DSTROOT/App
        echo "Redirected to working dir.."
        sudo hdiutil attach IntelDocker.dmg
        sudo /Volumes/Docker/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/install
        sudo hdiutil detach /Volumes/Docker
        sudo `$CheckVar load -i app.tar`
        echo "Success"
    fi
fi
```

Any solutions? been trying to solve this issue past 3 days.

Comment: what is the output of your script?

Comment: Try changing ``[[ `$CheckVar info` == *"Client"* ]]`` to `[ ! -z "$CheckVar" ]`

Comment: @ptierno load: command not found

Comment: Your script doesn't set the PATH as your text implies. Also you need to set PATH to the **directory that contains** docker, not to the docker binary itself, i.e. `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` and you should use forward slashes rather than nasty backwards Windows ones.

Comment: Well, yes, `load: command not found` is what you'd expect to happen from `$CheckVar load` when `CheckVar` is empty.

Comment: If you wrote `CheckVar=$(which docker) || exit` up front, your code wouldn't try to run at all when it couldn't find docker, instead of trying and being doomed to fail.

Comment: ...that said, it's a bad practice to store the output of `which` in the first place. `which` is slower than the shell's built-in PATH lookup, and that PATH lookup's results are cached so there's no performance benefit to saving its output explicitly. If you _did_ want to save the output of an explicit PATH lookup, `CheckVar=$(command -v docker) || exit` uses a POSIX-compliant shell builtin syntax instead of `which`, _and also_ forces the script to abort when the lookup fails, but I still recommend not trying to use CheckVar at all in the first place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if I dont use the absolute path of docker it gives docker: command not found error. What is the better approach or fix to this? I've added the path like mentioned and in the terminal docker commands working fine but only with scripts getting error.

Comment: It gives you that error for the same reason `which` doesn't work, being that `docker` isn't at a location in your PATH. Fix that and then _both_ approaches work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure your `PATH` is valid. It should contain the `directory` which the `docker` executable is stored in. Not the absolute path to the executable. Also, `execute PATH` is not how you set the value. You use `export`

`export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`

Change your tests from:

`` [ `$CheckVar info` == *"Client"* ]] `` to `[ "$CheckVar" ]`

from `man test`:

```
-n STRING
    the length of STRING is nonzero

STRING equivalent to -n STRING
```

The `CheckVar` variable is empty in the case where docker wasn't found on the system. Reset it in your `else` statements after installing docker.

```
sudo /Volumes/Docker/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/install
sudo hdiutil detach /Volumes/Docker
CheckVar=`which docker`
sudo $CheckVar load -i app.tar
```

Comment: `[ ! -z "$CheckVar" ]` is a rather long way to write `[ "$CheckVar" ]` or `[ -n "$CheckVar" ]`, no?

Comment: and `which` reports a nonzero exit status when it doesn't find a match, so you could just run `CheckVar=$(which docker) || exit` and not need to inspect the variable for emptiness in the first place.

Comment: (moreover, the POSIX-standard shell-builtin alternative to `which` is `command -v`, which is better used in preference).

Comment: Also, if you want to run `sudo docker load -i app.tar`, then you shouldn't have backticks around the `docker load -i app.tar` -- those backticks mean you're running the _output of_ `docker load` as a command (after string-splitting and glob-expanding that output).

Comment: I wasn't aware you could just provide the string to test without a flag. Thanks for that @CharlesDuffy

Comment: np -- it's the "1 argument" case in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: docker is installed still going to the else condition and installing docker and then getting error load: command not found. If I don't use the absolute path variable and directly use docker its giving docker not found frustrating.. docker info command is working in terminal without any issues, but not in script.

Comment: I've never used bash script and even macOS is new too me thats why i used backward slash while mentioning.. what am i doing wrong i just need to create automated script to check if docker is installed or not if its there load images but stuck since 3-4 days.

Comment: @grLearn all of your `sudo` commands have `````'s. you don't need those. If iy is saying `load: command not found` then the `CheckVar` variable is empty. it is moving to the else because your `$CheckVar info` test is failing.

Comment: @ptierno CheckVar is returning absolute path of docker but the command is not getting execute with variable probably thats why, I also tried without `` still getting same results of either `docker: command not found` or `load: command not found. ` Why bash script is not able to find docker tho?

Comment: @grLearn, we don't know where Docker is installed on your machine, and we don't know what PATH your script is running with, so how are we supposed to answer that question? You're literally the only person here who can answer it. Add `declare -p PATH` to your script to make it print the PATH (if you're running it with bash; `echo "$PATH"` otherwise is a little worse but generally okay), and run `which docker` in a separate window outside your script to figure out where Docker is installed.

Comment: Note that if the correct location is `/usr/bin/docker`, then your PATH needs to include `/usr/bin` -- **not** `/usr/bin/docker`, not `\usr\bin\docker`, not `\usr\bin`, _specifically_ `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @ptierno, btw, there's often not a reason to use `export` when modifying PATH, because 95% of the time PATH is already in an environment variable. `export` forces a shell variable to be copied to the environment, but if it's already there, then updates are automatically copied as well with or without `export`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy good to know. Learning a lot today.